# Tomcat7 trying to run a war that doesn't exist and then failing

Tags: java, tomcat

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Monocle does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Out tomcat7 is failing to start. to find if the issue is with tomcat itself or with my code, I deleted all the war files from the `webapps` folder except ROOT folder. When I started, it failed throwing the above error. `Monocle` is one war that I deleted. I don't understand why it is still trying to find Monocle. I already deleted `Catalina` folder from `work` folder. Can someone help me? do I need clear caches from any other location?

Comment: Make sure no docBase have been configured in tomcat setup. Its usually in server.xml I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to verify TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml file

In the  tag, appBase attribute has default value is wepapps, mabe you changed appBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Monocle".

Hope this helps!!!

ps: if not, add more information such. e.g:TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml, TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
```